# SameSite=Strict cookie, issued from AWS lambda, is not send for subdomain

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cookies, samesite

I have an AWS Lambda, hosted on domain `b.example.com`, that sends a 302 redirect response to location `a.example.com` with a `set-cookie` header for `Domain=example.com`.

```
headers: {
  "location": [{ key: "Location", value: 'a.example.com'}],
  "set-cookie": [{
    key: "Set-Cookie",
    value: `cookie.name=cookie-value; Domain=example.com; Max-Age=${maxAge}; SameSite=Strict; Secure; HttpOnly`
  }]
},
status: "302",
statusDescription: "redirect"
```

Browser saves the cookie (not rejected), but does not send the cookie with request header, when it request for `b.example.com`. It only sends the cookie if I set `SameSite=Lax`. The question is, does `SameSite=Strict` not work for subdomains? Is the only way to make it work is to use the `Lax` mode?

**Additional Details**

I tried to replicate the same scenario locally (w/o AWS) with 2 trivial `express.js` apps. One writes the cookie in response and the other reads it.

```
// generator
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.cookie('cookie-name', 'cookie-value', {
        domain: 'example.com',
        httpOnly: true,
        path: '/',
        sameSite: 'Strict',
        secure: true
    });
    res.redirect('https://b.example.com:3001');
});

// reader
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`cookies in req ${JSON.stringify(req.cookies)}`);
});
```

These are also 2 separate apps hosted on `https://a.example.com`, and `https://b.example.com` with self signed certs and all. Both the subdomains points to 127.0.0.1. And with this the same thing works w/o any hiccup.

Is there any reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: add domain=.example.com and browser will add it for both the subdomains.

Comment: Tried already w/o success. That should not matter anyway as RFC6265 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.2.3) says to ignore the preceeding `.`.